# Charting graph is mostly blank?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

Image for what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAiXX.jpg

So I'm setting up different graphs using Winforms Charting API, and normally they work OK, but for this big one in a Form.ShowDialog box, most of the chart is blank? I can see that the data is there, but there's a big blank area over most of the chart.

I've bought the chart to the front, and also made sure in the designer that there's nothing else that could be covering the graph.

All I'm doing to fill this new Form.ShowDialog box is:

```
//initialise chart object and chart areas/data here
...
ChartObject.ChartAreas[0].Position.Y = 0;
ChartObject.ChartAreas[0].Position.Height = 90;
ChartObject.ChartAreas[0].Position.X = 0;
ChartObject.ChartAreas[0].Position.Width = 90;

using (var frm = new Form())
{
    frm.Text = cc.ChartTitle;
    frm.Controls.Add(cc);
    cc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    frm.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

I'm completely stumped by this, as the graph is otherwise fully functional. Thanks.

Comment: What's the charting tool?

Comment: I think you forgot to initialize `ChartObject.DataSource=`

Comment: @CodingGorilla using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting; Not a tool.

Comment: @JaydipJadhav It's initialised (see top comment of code), as the data is definitely 100% there, it's just seemingly hidden behind something (see the top line of red underneath the chart title)

Comment: @ChrizC can show code of initialization

Comment: @JaydipJadhav I'm re-using this code for lots of different graphs, but basically how I setup the data source is this:

   ChartObject.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(ReportData.XValue, ReportData.YValue[0]);     ChartObject.Series["Series2"].Points.DataBindXY(ReportData.XValue, ReportData.YValue[1]);

Comment: @ChrizC   `ChartObject` and `cc` are same??

Comment: @JaydipJadhav cc is the Chart Control (a custom class of UserControl), ChartObject is the container of the ChartArea.

Comment: The code you show us is not the culprit. There must be something else going on. Are there other chartareas? Can you see the rest of the chartarea when you pick a backcolor like red?

Comment: @TaW This is what I see when I set backcolor to red: https://imgur.com/k5IgSnW (this should be a line graph with a white background) - so it seems the graph is rendering in the background, but something's blocking it.

Comment: @TaW should've also mentioned, this is the only ChartArea in this ChartObject.

Comment: Hm, seems to be weird indeed, as you say that the same code usually works fine. Since we don't see the UserControl, try to do a cc.BringToFront. (first add it at the end of the init code, then, to be sure in a button you press at runtime!)) I asume that you don't have any annotations..